# Is there anyway to detect if a user click like on a certain page in our website

Tags: asp.net, facebook, web

If there anyway to detect if a user clicks like on a page in our website so we can give some kind of reward for people clicking like on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use javascript that will fire up whenever user clicks the link

OR

you can utilize the Facebook api, quote:

> How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?
>
> If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to
>   the 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe.

Comment: cool,
can we check if like already click by that user when he come back again in case of anynymous user ? (login by facebook buy not login by our website )

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu, anonymous users are always a pain to deal with... You can store some info about him, like version of his browser + IP address. Then you'd need to check this every time he enters your website. Don't know if that's worth the hassle and know this isn't 100% reliable. Users can share the same IP, use same browser... I'd probably go the way: you want benefits, register, it's free! :) That is if I understood you correctly.